# Excel VBA Regex - how to match 3 characters when there may be other characters in between

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I'm dealing with some data that has some odd symbols (from some other language)

Im writing a macro in excel that uses regular expressions, and I'd like to match "1x2" when the string contains 1â€xâ€2

Comment: can't you use that in the regex?!

Comment: Have you tried using the regex as `1â€xâ€2` itself?

Comment: Well, there's a lot more iterations than just the 1â€xâ€2. It's a pattern that occurs throughout the data.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide some more samples?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use `1.x.2`.  If there is no guarantee that there *will* be characters between them, `1.?x.?2` should work.

Comment: `1.x.2` matches exactly 5 characters.  `1.?x.?2` doesnt work either for the example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **\u####** in a regex to match a character by its Unicode number, where **####** is the Unicode number in hex. The hex Unicode for â is 00E2, and the hex Unicode for € is 20AC, so this regex

```
1\u00E2\u20ACx\u00E2\u20AC2
```

will match **1â€xâ€2**.

Is that what you were looking for? I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "*match* '1x2' when the string *contains* 1â€xâ€2". Are you saying that you want to match the sequence **1â€xâ€2** itself (which is what the regex above will do), or match **1x2** in strings that contain **1â€xâ€2** somewhere else (which is what your wording seems to imply, but I have the feeling that's not what you mean), or that you want to replace **1â€xâ€2** with **1x2**?

---

EDIT:
Actually, based on the question's title, where you say "there *may* be other characters in between", you'll want this regex, which makes those "other characters" optional:

```
1(\u00E2\u20AC)?x(\u00E2\u20AC)?2
```

This will match any of the following:

- 1â€xâ€2
- 1x2
- 1â€x2
- 1xâ€2

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will return the desired string components.

I have assumed that rather than 1 or 2 you actually wanted any numeric match. If not change `"(\d).*?(x).*?(\d)"` to `"(1).*?(x).*?(2)"`

```
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim strIn As String
strIn = "1â€xâ€2"
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
.Pattern = "(\d).*?(x).*?(\d)"
If .test(strIn) Then MsgBox .Replace(strIn, "$1$2$3")
End With
```